# ARDUINO : Hold Values & Serial monitor

Tags: arduino

i would like to ask .
I am doing LED project using serial monitor.
if key for serial monitor 1 is pressed one time , LED 1 will light up until i pressed the 2nd key for serial monitor 2 and LED 2 will light up .

how can i do that? 
by delay() ? or hold () ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `delay()` because the time taken until next the next keypress cannot be determined.

You can use flags, as demonstrated below

```
int ledPin1 = 8, ledPin2 = 9;
boolean flag1, flag2;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
    if(Serial.available())
    {
        int c = Serial.read();
        if(c == 49) { // 1 is pressed
            flag1 = true;
            flag2 = false;
        }
        else if(c == 50) { // 2 is pressed
            flag2 = true;
            flag1 = false;
        }
    }
    if(flag1) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
    }
    if(flag2) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
    }
    delay(50);
}
```

Hope this helps.